# Way to remove duplicate frames in screencast with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, screencasts

I have recorded a screencast from a coding session. In there are many times where the screen is still and I have to think about the code. I want to remove all of these frames automatically with FFmpeg.

I have tried out different filters like mpdecimate or select, but it doesn´t work very well. The problem with mpdecimate was that it cuts out every dublicated frame. For example it finds duplicated frames while I am writing new code which speeds up the video and I don´t want this. I only want to cut out the freeze frames which are longer than for example 1 second.

I found a filter which prints very helpful metadata. The filter is called [freezedetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#freezedetect).

Is there a way to use the output from the freezedetect filter and trim the video accordingly or do you know a better technique to remove the afk frames?

I have included a test video where you can see all the still frames.

Thanks for your help and time :)

[Test Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d28tdTIOW6LDQZhDlvd_WhIC_EvTgOLZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think the trick is passing that metadata into `freezeframes`. At least that's the approach I'm taking as of now.

Comment: Did either of you ever solve this?